# How to reply to a thread in a mailing list which is not in my Inbox

Tags: mailing-lists

I have subscribed to a mailing list.
Then I have seen a thread where I can add a possibly useful post.

**How can I add to that thread?**

If I had that email in my Inbox, I could reply to it.

PS: I wouldn't be sure if SuperUser or any other is the most suited SE site for this.

PS2:

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351394/how-do-i-reply-to-a-sourceforge-mailing-list) has 11 upvotes, but I am not sure it is correct (see the comments).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953844/answering-to-a-mailing-list) has no answers.

Comment: This is off-topic here. It *could* be on-topic on Web Apps, but as written it's too broad and cannot be migrated there in its current condition.

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23197/19408

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most mailing lists use the In-Reply-To or the Reply-To field to thread the messages. Do you see a "Reply to:" function on the page? Clicking that should open your default mail client with the correct headers. An example is the [Debian list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2018/02/msg00000.html) , it uses:

```
<a href="mailto:debian-user@lists.debian.org?In-Reply-To=<20180201020517.GA18805@alum>&amp;Subject=Re:%20Re: Network setup by installer">debian-user@lists.debian.org</a>
```

Or you could use the mbox archives many lists have. 
For example the [Ubuntu bugs archives](http://people.canonical.com/~listarchive/ubuntu-bugs/) where you can look at the headers and insert them in your mail (if your mail client supports that). Alternatively you can download the mbox files and use/import them, again the how depends on your mail client.

Based on your comment I checked out the mailing list. If you go this [example](https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2018-February/041865.html) at the top you can click:

[image]

That should open in your mail client. If you ask me they could have made that more obvious.

Comment: This is the mailing list https://www.paraview.org/mailman/listinfo/paraview . Among the options you provide: 1) "Reply to:" function on the page... Not available, 2) mbox archives + headers... Maybe https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/ I would need to know which header is relevant, possibly Message-ID, 3) download+import mbox... Possible (but cumbersome).

Comment: I cannot test the answer right now, but it very much looks like exactly what I need.
As you say, it could have been more clearly indicated.

Comment: I've tested this and it works, i.e. I copied the message-id from a web-archive and manually set the `In-Reply-To: <msg-id>` header in mutt (i.e. `SHIFT+E`). The mailing list software properly threaded the message then.